# How do I kick off an executable from a web page?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, url, url-protocol

We have rewritten a WinForms app A as a web app.  The old WinForms app had integration with WinForms app B, in that you could fire it up from app A with a set of variables.

Users are now demanding the same functionality from a rewritten web app.  My first thought was for WinForms app B to create my own URL protocol (foo://...), but it seems that to do that you have to create keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT - which is an activity done by an admin user.  However, the users are basically limited users and WinForms app B is actually a ClickOnce app.

What are my options?

Comment: does app b talk to a server that the web app talks to?

Comment: You can create an installer that an admin would install on client machines. After all that's what an admin's job is.

Comment: When you say "integration", what **exactly** do you mean? How did it "integrate" previously? Was it a command line call? Something else? Also, where do these applications live? Client side? Server side?

Comment: @HighCore that makes no sense - web applications do not share the same filesystem with desktop applications so memory-mapped files don't make much sense (unless through a network share, I guess?). Please share more details of this approach of yours :)

Comment: @DanielA.White No, it doesn't.  The web app A is in the cloud, while app B is on a local server.

Comment: It seems that these are client side apps and the integration amounts to a command line call (or perhaps data are passed via environment variables).

Comment: @Oded The "integration" meant that app A created a file in the temp folder on the fly with a set of parameters (quiet complex) and then command line called app B with the file as the command line parameter.  App A now lives in the cloud (Salesforce) and App B is a local app that connects to a local database/web service.

Comment: @HighCore Could you expand on a concept of a memory mapped file? I know how client apps talk via MMF. How does a web app create that?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: Memory mapped files will not help in this case. The problem is that App A is now sandboxed in the browser - it cannot do any of these on the client machine: 1. Create files, 2. Call items on the command line, 3. Use memory mapped files.

Comment: @All - this is just to add to the discussion, it's ultimately bad form but could be a workaround.  Can you create dynamic links on the web app based on user?  You'd need to capture their local workstation name and create a link like **<a href="\\workstation_name\c$\windows\system32\cmd.exe">Run Cmd</a>**.  Replace this exe with App B.  There are a ton of assumptions here, like Users have LA on their PC, web app A allows links like this, you're allowed to run apps, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since App A is now in the cloud and the user interacts with it via the browser, it is sandboxed and many of the things that a desktop app can do are not available to it anymore.

This is a security feature and outside of writing a browser plugin that will bridge between App a on the browser and App b, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Well a java applet with appropriate permissions would work too.

Comment: @zespri - Java runs as a plugin inside the browser, no?

Comment: @zespri also would a Silverlight application, but we're talking about WEB applications, without any plug-ins or add-ons. BTW, java stuff is disabled on the majority of browsers, because it really sucks in terms of security.

Comment: @Oded, sure, it's just you were talking about *writing* a plug-in and I'm pointing out that you don't need to write one.